# Customization of keystone js (Node CMS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, content-management-system, keystonejs

I am working on keystone. I am stuck in a issue where we have two fields that are dependent on one an other.

```
    country: {type: Types.Select, required: true, initial: true, options: 'Pakistan'},
 state: {type: Types.Select, required: true, initial: true, label: 'State/Province', options: 'Punjab, Sindh'}.
```

Here, there is one country and its state. But the  problem is that how to change state dropdown on country select. I want to change state select option on change of country dropdown. I am tried by watching the field but it doesn't works. Any suggestion/direction?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're asking. You want to change the value of the state dropdown, but only after a specific country is selected. Is that right?

Comment: yes that the use case. The country and state name is in array not coming from database

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dependsOn` attribute of a field in your document.

http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fields-conditional

```
country: { type: Types.Select, required: true, initial: true, options: 'Pakistan'},
state:   { type: Types.Select, required: true, initial: true, dependsOn: { country: 'Pakistan' }, label: 'State/Province', options: 'Punjab, Sindh'}.
```

You would add the following to your field:

```
dependsOn: { country: 'Pakistan' }
```

In the Keystone Admin UI, the `state` field would only be displayed to users if `country` is equal to `Pakistan`. The field can still be set by your code, but it cannot be set through the UI (web browser).